# Azure Function Func.exe "host start" with multiple directories

Tags: azure, azure-functions

Is it possible for a single func.exe to host multiple function projects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not today. The Azure Functions runtime only supports a single script root, which is what the CLI bootstraps it with.

If you can share more about  your scenario, please open an issue with the details here: https://github.com/azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues

Comment: My scenario is to keep things simple when a developer is running everything locally. It would be nice for someone new to the team to clone the repo and for the website to run a single func.exe automatically for all of the functions we use, so it works 'out of the box'.

Comment: ... so maybe be the question should be: how do you set up a nice developer run / debug experience when you have an ASP.NET MVC application and numerous function projects all in the same solution, where the entire application is relying on all of them. In particular, we'd like the developer to be able to build at any point without "file in use" errors and have those changes reflected on the site and functions when they visit the website locally through IIS.